# C# migration custom SELECT SQL script

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I am very new to C# world and I would like to perform custom SQL command inside a migration script. There are a lot of examples of how to execute `UPDATE/CREATE` but not how to use results from it, for example `SELECT`.

Here is what I have in the migration file:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    var result = migrationBuilder.Sql($"SELECT something from some table");
    ...
}
```

I would like to use the `result` from the custom `SELECT query` for some condition down below.

`migrationBuilder.Sql` returns `SqlOperation` type, which I am not sure how can I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't actually get results of a query inside a migration. Migrations are only intended for modifying schema or data in the database.
If you need to have some condition to execute a script - well, that's only achievable by writing it with a native SQL.